# Changed category name but new name is not showing on front-end

Tags: category, cache

I changed a category name, `refresh and flush all cache and reindex some related category`

but on front-end, the new name is not showing and old name is still showing

```
(it seems changing url is working)
```

Delete all files on var/cache and var/sessions

```
What I have to do or check more to show new category name on front-end?
```

Comment: Do you have flat tables enabled?  If so, and you have access to the database, can you check your `catalog_category_flat_store_1` table and see if the name is correct there? If not, it's likely related to indexing  - if so, it's related to caching.

Comment: @PhilBirnie could you pls help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/211611/57334

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be that you have multiple stores and the category name defined on a store view level.

If you do have multiple stores select the store view your trying to see on the frontend from [image]

And check that it is set to "Use Default" as below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @James, I have same problem, But I have done renaming by selecting default store view, And my other store view scope checked as use default value. What is the problem and how can I solve it

Comment: anyone help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/211611/57334