# Issue - Multi-Store Category Disable Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, category, multistore, store-view, category-tree

I have disabled one of my categories, but still the category display on my menu bar in the website.

How can I solve this issue?

Menu Extension :

https://web-experiment.info/webandpeople-custom-menu-extension

**Backend :**

[image]

**Website:**

[image]

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: check is there any configuration in backend  for adding or deleting `menu items`.....

Comment: I didn't get you, you mean is any backend code configuration?

Comment: yes, there many be some configuration in backend for adding or deleting menus if you are using custom theme.....

Comment: Is possible can I remove the category name from UI Part, I mean website front end menu bar.

Comment: @BabyinMagento check my updated question.

Comment: Did you do a reindex? Maybe categories are enabled per singles store view?

Comment: @FraH Yes i re-indexed, still error.

Comment: Check if the categorie arent enabled in one of store view?

Answer (score 3):

Well No one can answer this question until and unless they see your code.

What logic theme/or menu extension has written for fetching categories.

But I can give you a hint where you start debug this issue.

Go to the `System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer`

and change your scope to `website/store`

then enable `template path hint` and check from which `PHTML` this menu comes.

then find block class for that `PHTML` and in block class you will get the actual logic for menu rendering.